# get_selectedItems()[0] on RadGrid returns null

Tags: javascript, .net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I have a problem with the  `get_selectedItems()` function.
I use `RadGrid` from `Telerik`. Great controls, but now I  stumbled on a bug which I can not solve.

When selecting a row, I call the `RowSelectionChanged` function on the client side and then I'll get an exception.

Could anyone tell me why `sender.get_selectedItems()[0]` is null while `sender.get_selectedItems().length` is at least 1?

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function RowSelectionChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
            if (sender != null) {
                for (i = 0; i < sender.get_selectedItems().length; i++) { 
                    var it = sender.get_selectedItems()[i];     // it is null
                            var element =it.get_element();  // throws exception
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>

</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgTest" runat="server" >
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn"  />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="guid" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
        <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelectionChanged" />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `get_selectedItems()` should be invoked NOT on RadGrid object but on  MasterTableView object.

This code works for me:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function RowSelectionChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
            if (sender != null) {
                var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
                for (i = 0; i < masterTable.get_selectedItems().length; i++) { 
                    var it = masterTable.get_selectedItems()[i];     
                    var element =it.get_element(); 
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```